# What does "in a nut shell" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

I know what a nut shell is:

[image: a walnut shell]

But what is its meaning in this sentence:

> In a nut shell I'm trapped mentally and physically.

In this a common expression? Does it mean that he's closed in himself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is quite a common expression. This is similar to saying ... *in short...* But I understand that the confusion is due to *nut shell* and *trap*. He's not trapped into the nutshell!

[TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+nutshell) has an entry for that and it is an idiomatic way to say that.

> *in a nutshell* - *In a few words; concisely*

So, he's not fitting himself into that little space but *comprising the matter* that might fit well into it! :) Said that, he's telling something in short without adding much explanation.

It's often used when you don't want to get into a long description or explanation.

Comment: +1 The underlying image is that you are reducing a complicated topic to something so small it will fit *in a nutshell*.

Comment: Note that we can write 'nut shell', 'nut-shell' and 'nutshell'. Google Ngrams shows 'nutshell' and 'in a nutshell' used more than the other choices. I seem to remember a  children's story about a very small character who slept in a nutshell, but couldn't find any reference to that online. I did find many 'advice for parents' websites with titles like 'Baby sleep: in a nutshell' (and one titled 'College psychology in a nutshell').

Comment: @Sydney: was the very small character male or female? If male, you're probably thinking of *Tom Thumb*, and if female, *Thumbelina*.

Answer (score 2):

*In a nutshell* is often said *after* one has explained in depth a topic. It is a **summary** of the events.

In the example provided, I could imagine the speaker talking about his/her personal problems.

**Their psychological well-being**:

- My  kids never talk to me. (They don't respect me.)
- The neighbour's dog barks at night and it's not safe to go out at night.
- I think my spouse is having an affair. (I wish I could get a divorce)
- My boss expects me to work 14 hours per day. (I hate my job)
- If I complain, I might get laid off. (I have a mortgage to pay)

**Their economic situation**:

1. I can't leave my job
2. I can't move home
3. I can't afford to leave my spouse
4. The kids will be starting college soon

> *In a nutshell* OR *in other words*, I'm trapped mentally and physically

Answer (score 1):

This is a metaphor. The inside of a nutshell is a small space; hence anything "in a nutshell" has been compressed into a small space, in other words: summarized. The context given is not in itself a common usage and the "nutshell" is not a reference to the state of being trapped.

As with so many of these metaphors, it is a cliché and should generally be avoided in favour either of something fresher, or something straight-forward.