# What does the nutshell in “in a nutshell” stand for?

Tags: meaning, idioms, metaphors, etymology

I know the meaning of “in a nutshell” but do not know what *“nutshell”* or *“nut”* itself stands for in this idiom.

Since it is a metaphor, I would like to know what it recalls to the speakers/listeners’ mind whose first langage is English. Etymology of the idiom would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [The underlying image is that you are reducing a complicated topic to something so small it will fit in a nutshell. – StoneyB](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/33942/what-does-in-a-nut-shell-mean-in-this-context/34023#comment63670_33944)

Comment: Thanks! Though I skimmed that question before posting mine, I didn't notice this comment...

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, welcome to ELL!

Comment: An example of a nutshell being used to mean a small space is Hamlet Act II, Scene 2, "I could be bounded in a nutshell, and count myself a king of infinite space—were it not that I have bad dreams".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [shell of a nut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutshell) tends to be small and compact, which is why "in a nutshell" is used to mean "in a few words," or, more literally, "in a compact statement."

According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_a_nutshell#Etymology), the etymology is as follows:

> A calque of Latin *in nuce*.

"[Calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calque)" means "a word for word translation," and "*[in nuce](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_nuce#Latin)*" means "in a nut" in Latin.

Answer (score 15):

I think that by definition, idioms have to be understood in their entirety; the meaning of the idiom does not necessarily correspond to the meaning of the individual words.

However, a *nutshell* is the shell, or outer covering, of a nut.  Like this:

[image]

Inside a nutshell is a very small space, where you couldn't put very much.  If you were trying to put an explanation inside a nutshell, it would have to be a very small one! - so "in a nutshell" means "in a very small and simple way".

Comment: This is exactly what I picture.

Answer (score 6):

According to some historical rumors, Pliny the Elder wrote that Cicero once found a copy of Homer's *Iliad*, written in minuscule letters compressed in a nutshell. Now the *Iliad* isn't particularly concise or anything, but that seems to be the origin of the concept as we know it today, if not the idiom itself. Here's a likeness of Pliny (AD 23- AD 79):

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "tiny" rather than "puny"?

Comment: @psmears: Minuscule, actually.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense :)

Comment: According to other historical rumours, Pliny the Elder wrote an awful lot of bull****.